# getting array of child values from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

database structure

[image: database structure]

I am trying to get an array of users(strings) from a comment, but am having trouble since it is kinda deep in my database, here is the implementation I've tried, it is returning 0 for the count.

```
REF_FEEDMESSAGES.child(messageKey).child("comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (commentSnapshot) in
            guard let commentSnapshot = commentSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

            for comment in commentSnapshot {

                let theComment = comment.value as? [String: Any]

                let theContent = theComment?["content"] as? String ?? ""
                let theIcon = theComment?["icon"] as? String ?? ""
                let theColor = theComment?["color"] as? String ?? ""
                let theDate = theComment?["date"] as? String ?? "0"
                let theName = theComment?["userName"] as? String ?? ""
                let theVerified = theComment?["isVerified"] as? String ?? "no"
                let profileImageURL = theComment?["profileImageURL"] as? String ?? ""
                let postedBy = theComment?["postedBy"] as? String ?? ""
                let likes = theComment?["likes"] as? String ?? ""
                let key = comment.key

                let likers = comment.childSnapshot(forPath: "likedBy").value as? [String] ?? []
                print(likers.count)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
guard let likers = comment.childSnapshot(forPath: "likedBy").children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
                for like in likers {
                    let theLike = like.value as? [String:Any]
                    print(theLike!["user"] as? String ?? "")
                    commentLiked.append(theLike!["user"] as? String ?? "")
                }
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally not helpful. It's a good idea to include some information about what the code does or how it solves the problem presented in the question. In this case, it doesn't match the Firebase structure presented in the question. Is this a solution? An additional issue? Something else?